# get a list of facebook pages that has word "xyxyx"

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I'm pretty new facebook api. So, i have decided to build an app which displays a list of facebook pages starting has the word "xxyyxxy".

I have looked into facebook documentation and found that i could use Facebook graph API which is public API. 
A get request like `https://graph.facebook.com/stackoverflow` would fetch a JSON array with that particular page details but i need list of all pages with this word in its name.Any suggestions are appreciated.

For example,

I send a get request to facebook api to fetch all pages with keyword "robin"
and facebook should return me all pages which has the word "robin" in it and the respective facebook page link, display picture of the page, number of likes just similarly how `https://graph.facebook.com/stackoverflow` returns details of particular page.

Comment: What would be example output of your concern? Could you write?

Comment: You should check out facebook graph api and FQL https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/. With fql you may be able to do this kind of queries.

Comment: @Prakash i have added an example scenario.

Comment: @Bartdude what should i try when i dont know which query gives these results?

Comment: @Mirage > read the doc, google it, ask on forums, ... You know, developer stuff. Although you might get an answer or remark pointing you in the right direction (which I don't know), SO is not the place for such questions. I nyway doubt this is possible regarding the huge amount of records to search through

Answer (score 0):

here the FQL Query:

```
select page_id, name, pic from page where contains('xyxyxyx')
```

if you need other data check this page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for facebook search. You can do it this way:

`http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=xyxyx&type=page&limit=10`

Make a callback to this URL with your API key. For reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference

Comment: Can this be achieved with Javascript alone?

Comment: You just gotta process `http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=xyxyx&type=page&limit=10`